# Firebase "too_big" error querying a ref with huge number of children

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is how I query my firebase database.

```
var firebase = require("firebase-admin");
// initialization steps...

firebase.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('email').equalTo('someemail@somedomain.com')
        .once('value')
        .then(snapshot=>{
          const records = snapshot.val();
          console.log("value is: ", records);
        })
        .catch(err=> console.log(err));
```

So I have an immediate child of root `Users` which has several thousand children. Each child(A individual user identified by a firebase generated key) has an attribute `email` (among others)

When I query it like that, I get this error:

```
{ Error: too_big at /Users: The data requested exceeds the maximum size that can be accessed with a single request.
```

So how do I query for this value?

Comment: did you find any answer for this issue? I'm looking for something similar